# First word won't save in post or edit

Tags: bug, editor

I recently wrote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52033544/1586231) on Stack Overflow.  In order to be nice and in the spirit of our push toward welcoming new users, I began my answer with

> Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

When I hit "post", the answer got published with the first word cut off, so the first sentence is just

> and welcome to Stack Overflow!

I tried editing it twice to add the `Hi,` to no avail.  I did not get any warning message, it just didn't save my changes.  I then hypothesized that perhaps `Hi,` was too few characters, so I tried `Hi @username_of_the_OP,` which also did not work, and again no error message or indication of an error of any sort, it just didn't save my changes.

I think this is a bug in the site, and am posting here to report it.  I hope this helps.

If this is actually a bug in me (ie, user error) please let me know and I will fix my erroneous ways :D

Comment: The answer in that post you're specifically looking for is the second one: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/284336 - this is intentional. The system automatically removes such greetings. :)

Comment: Wow, thanks for telling me!  This is confusing though, because I am under the impression that I'm [**supposed**](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/) to say things like "Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow!" .... am I just supposed to reserve vernacular greetings for my comments / edit suggestions, and not use them in my answers?  Thanks!

Comment: We do want people to be welcoming but that doesn't need to appear in their posts. Posts still need to focus on content and avoid salutations and signatures. Think of it this way, two years from now, your post may still be around - the asker probably doesn't still need to be welcomed at that point.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for the clarification!